# Convert key value pairs with duplicate keys into a Counter

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections

I've got this in Python 2.7

```
l = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4)]
```

How do I get a Counter c where:

```
c = Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 7 }]
```

I would prefer to use comprehension if possible or the fastest possible way to do this.

Comment: Curious: why do you prefer a comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate and add, `Counter` takes care of this automatically!

```
In [5]: l = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4)]
    ...:

In [6]: c = Counter()

In [7]: for k, v in l:
    ...:     c[k] += v
    ...:

In [8]: c
Out[8]: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 7})
```

This is how `Counter` is designed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, map(lambda x: Counter({x[0]: x[1]}), l))
Counter({'b': 7, 'a': 3})
```

Or `sum`:

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x: Counter({x[0]: x[1]}), l), Counter())
Counter({'b': 7, 'a': 3})
```

Comment: Use `sum` instead of `reduce` and `operator.add`

Comment: I tried `sum(map(lambda x: Counter({x[0]: x[1]}), l))` but got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'`, then switched to use `reduce` and `operator.add`. Just found I need to specify the default `start` parameter for `sum`. Thanks for your info, I updated my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sort and group by the key; sum the values for each key; add key:sum(values) to a dictionary.

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4)]
>>> key = operator.itemgetter(0)
>>> value = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> a.sort(key = key)
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, group in itertools.groupby(a, key = key):
    d[k] = sum(map(value, group))

>>> d
{'a': 3, 'b': 7}
>>>
```

or

```
>>> g = {k:sum(map(value, group)) for k, group in itertools.groupby(a, key = key)}
>>> g
{'a': 3, 'b': 7}
>>>
```

---

You don't really need a collections.Counter

Comment: You *definitely* don't need `itertools.groupby` and a `sort`! Just use `setdefault` or `get(x, 0)`! ... or just use `Counter`.

Comment: Concur, but I like itertools.

Comment: Sure, but you are trading an O(n) solution for a O(n*logn) solution... Maybe not the end of the world...

Comment: Well, if it is a bad solution a minus one is in order.